# 18.04/18.10 cannot run on Asus FX503VD laptop

Tags: system-installation, asus, compatibility

The laptop is Asus FX503VD and I tried ubuntu 18.04 and 18.10.  After installation finished and I pressed the "Restart Now", the system always halt without actual reboot.  I can then power off by pressing the power button then entered the system in the case of 18.10; In 18.04, the desktop will not show up after I entered the password.  Even the 18.10 can allow me to enter the desktop, but it halted in the step 2 or step 3 of the "welcome to ubuntu" wizard.  I can open the terminal, but the system again halt after  I run one or two simple commands.  It seemed there was always 100% CPU program in the top of the 'top' list.

Is that possible I can use ubuntu with this laptop? Thanks!

Comment: Just noticed, the laptop is FX63VD, just the ubuntu installer said it is a FX503VD.

Comment: And, I found I can run the "live ubuntu" from the installation usb without a problem.  It looks like a hope ...

Comment: Does it have a Nvidia graphics card?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia, yes it has a Nvidia GTX 1050 graphics card.  Is this the root cause?

Comment: It certainly is if you didn't install the recommended Nvidia proprietary drivers. Search for "Software & Updates", open the "Additional Drivers" tab, select and apply the recommended driver version, reboot. You may need to add the `nomodeset` boot parameter until you do it, otherwise it may not boot a GUI or freeze when it does. The default open-source driver for Nvidias does not properly support yet the new chips.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia, thanks!  Now the problem is I cannot properly run "Software & Updates" before I set the nomodeset, the system is completely not function well. So I am thinking to add the nomodeset parameter after I completed the installation and reboot into the LiveCD mode.  In this mode, can you tell me how do I add the 'nomodeset' parameter?  It looks like it's not easy in LiveCD mode.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu/ Of course, after installing the drivers you won't need this parameter.

Comment: Hi @GabrielaGarcia, you may not understand my problem, I have no way to enter the "software & updates" in order to install the driver, I halted in the "Welcome to unbuntu" screen.

Comment: The link above explains how to boot an already installed system with `nomodeset`. What is the problem exactly? I DO understand your problem very well - you're the ~10.000 user here posting a variant of the exact same theme -, the question is do you know what you're doing? Have you understood already what the problem is and why you need `nomodeset` until you install the Nvidia drivers? If not please explain what you don't understand instead of assuming that's me who don't understand...

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia, sorry I should not miss the link :)   That's a very clear intro, but unfortunately I still cannot enter grub meter by holding the shift key -- I tried left shift, right shift, both shifts a lot of time, pressing it immediately after power on or before power on.  No way is working ...  Do you have an experience about this?  (BTW: I do know what is nomodeset is for :)  I was a Slackware user before, just new to ubuntu)

Comment: Hello @GabrielaGarcia, I just found a way to show up the grub menu by editing /etc/defaults/grub in the LiveCD mode, and I then added the 'nomodeset' kernel parameter.  But this did not save me, the ubuntu booted with a black screen immediately after the splash, left a white cursor blinking forever at the upper left corner of the display :(   What should I do?  Tks.

Comment: Have you actually edited the one from the installed system? The same exists for the live session's file system.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076#162076 Follow the instructions starting at "Black/purple screen after you boot Ubuntu for the first time".

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia.  After boot into LiveCD mode, I chroot into my real SSD partition, edit the /etc/defaults/grub followed with 'update-grub' command.  It took effect, otherwise the shift key should not work.  The modifications I did to the grub config file is just to bring up the grub menu (otherwise it is hidden causing the shift key not to work) and did not change the kernel parameter here.  After I saw the grub menu I then change the kernel parameter after pressing 'e' on the grub menu item.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia.  After boot into LiveCD mode, I chroot into my real SSD partition, edit the /etc/defaults/grub followed with 'update-grub' command.  It took effect, otherwise the shift key should not work.  The modifications I did to the grub config file is just to bring up the grub menu (otherwise it is hidden causing the shift key not to work) and did not change the kernel parameter here.  After I saw the grub menu I then change the kernel parameter after pressing 'e' on the grub menu item.

Comment: Hi buddlies, I just learned, in additional to 'nomodeset', I also need to remove 'splash' and '$vt_handoff'.  Now I got a successful boot and installed the nvidia driver, the system looks working good.  Thanks for all your help!